# Boltzmann equation derivation for $H=v\sigma \cdot p$ hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, kinetic-theory

I am trying to write the Boltzmann equation for $$H=v_{F}\vec{\sigma}\cdot(\vec{p}-e\vec{A}).$$ This is a free charged particles gas. The velocity for this hamiltonian is $$\vec{v}=v_{F} \vec{\sigma}.$$ The Lorentz force can be derived $\vec{F}=q(\vec{v}\times \vec{B})$. 
I am considering to start from  $$\frac
{df}{dt}=\frac
{\partial f}{\partial t}+\vec{F}\cdot\vec{\nabla}_{p}f(\vec{p},\vec{\sigma},\epsilon).$$
I am trying to rigorously reach to boltzmann equation from this hamiltonian.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in detail in the paper *Chiral Kinetic theory* by Stephanov and Yin arXiv:1207.0747

Comment: Thanks @ mike stone